# Can someone explain the playing style of the great Jose Raul Capablanca?

Tags: strategy, tactics, capablanca, capablanca-chess

I have heard that he plays intuitively(maybe based on themes), but can someone give an example?

How did he manage to reach such heights despite his laziness for calculations?

Doesn't that mean even a mediocre  player can reach great rankings if he just plays intuitively?

Comment: Maybe Capablanca could explain it to you. He did write a book. It is called *Chess Fundamentals*

Comment: He studied deeply when he was 12, and chess didn't change much during his lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if your intuition is good enough:)

You overlook the training and experience he had.  Emanuel Lasker said he did not memorize anything he can deduce.

From my playing over his games he was a quiet patient positional player who could mix it up if the situation forced him to do that.